# zeus is getting hung on boot process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeus

I'm using [zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) 0.15.4 on my project and it's recently stopped working. I tried updating zeus but it still gets to the boot phase and just hangs there (coloured blue for connecting).
If I start zeus like so in my rails 3.2.x project

```
zeus --log log/zeus.log start
```

Then I get this log

```
2015/07/22 10:27:44.643477 [/Users/nick/Work/gopath/src/github.com/burke/zeus/go/processtree/slavenode.go:184] boot/(no PID) in unbooted state
2015/07/22 10:27:44.644935 [/Users/nick/Work/gopath/src/github.com/burke/zeus/go/processtree/slavenode.go:372] boot/(no PID) running the root command now
2015/07/22 10:27:45.314983 [/Users/nick/Work/gopath/src/github.com/burke/zeus/go/processtree/slavenode.go:217] boot/(29736) in booting state
```

Comment: No, I've currently disabled zeus.